# Javascript transition on click after display block

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, display

im trying to make a simple transition from right to left when i click on a button.

I've done this to illustrate what i mean : https://jsfiddle.net/Waarx/9kjhnwLp/22/

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
button1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('#display2').style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector('#display1').style.display = "block";
});

var button2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
button2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('#display2').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('#display1').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 800px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.col2 {
  width: 70%;
}

.none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#" id="div1">Div1</a>
    <a href="#" id="div2">Div2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="none" id="display1">
      display 1
    </div>
    <div class="none" id="display2">
      display 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that you could help me.

Comment: It's not clear from your code what/where you want to transition. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've add the whole code. So, for exemple, when i click on the "Div1", i want to show "display 1" with a simple animation from the right to the left like here : http://techfunda.com/Examples/Show/1148

Comment: Can you use the code in the example you've provided? (from techfunda)

Comment: Please use the bracket button: `<>` to open the Snippet editor. Place your code within that editor.

Answer (score 0):

First off you can do the same thing with jQuery like this with less code:

```
$('#div1').click(function(event) {
  $('#display2').hide();
  $('#display1').show();
});

$('#div2').click(function(event) {
  $('#display2').show();
  $('#display1').hide();
});
```

Secondly: To animate an html element you have to set its *opacity*. `display: none;` [will not animate at all](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/). Also using only classes makes you lose less time on your CSS. So,

#### Test it here:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.div1').click(function(event) {
      $('.display2').addClass('none');
      $('.display1').removeClass('none');
    });

    $('.div2').click(function(event) {
      $('.display2').removeClass('none');
      $('.display1').addClass('none');
    });
});
```

```css
.display1, .display2 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.none {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">
      <a href="#" class="div1">Div1</a>
      <a href="#" class="div2">Div2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="display1 none">
       display 1
    </div>
    <div class="display2 none">
      display 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```